# Opening an URL when clicking a Marker (Google Maps Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, marker

When you place a Marker on a Google Map Fragment you can touch (click) this to get a small "Pop-Up" with aditional information. Can I open a URL by clicking on this Pop-up once more? If in a browser or whatever wouldn't matter.

Is it possible and ìf, how?

Comment: It's possible but what have you done anything before asking?

Comment: Placing markers all over the map wit data received from a XML file so I have the markers but not anything to tackle this problem especially because I read something that indicated that it is not possible and the lack of content i found on google supported this theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click marker, you will pass title and snippet in your popup window
If you want to pass when you click popup, use `onInfoWindow()` to open URL...

```
Googlemap gm;
gm.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        //Do your stuff here by passing url.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0){
    String url = "https://www.google.com";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation.

Comment: Please edit your question to add a *readable* explanation to the code, instead of hiding it in a comment. The idea is to make the answer readable, clear and helpful - which in turn might earn you some upvotes. You might want to consider using English instead of SMS-English for that.